# How do I prevent z fighting for duplicate array objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

[image]

Hey Guys, I am trying to create this procedural watch band like this:
[image]

But everytime I try to ensure a minimal x or z offset for the duplicated array objects(to ensure smooth continuation of array and no z fighting) once I turn rendered view back on I get the error again. How do I eliminate this error and make sure the wrist band is in one flow and doesn't have any edges popping out like this image:
[image]

https://gofile.io/d/ipPBec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model by hand as little as possible.

This is really the only thing you need to be modelling by hand, one quarter segment. Mine is simplified to a 2D element, yours will likely need to be 3D and have the holes factored in, but you get the idea.

[image]

The rest you should let modifiers do it for you, in a as hands-off approach as possible.

[image]

1. Model a quarter segment
2. Add a *Mirror* modifier in the two symmetry axis
3. Add an *Array* modifier
4. Set it to *Fit Curve* and pick your bracelet curve
5. Add a *Merge* threshold small enough to not eat your details
6. Add a *Curve* modifier and pick you curve.
7. Optionally add bespoke *Array* cap objects to make the start and end caps of the bracelet

[image]

Comment: I never thought about trying this method out where you model a quarter segment and mirror it to create this geo, how would you achieve this using primitives(like cylinders or circles for eg, as I was struggling by trying directly duplicating those meshes) and also why wouldn't you choose that method( I understood why the z fighting was so pertinent in my model lol, many thanks man